# Android Emulator Library Not Found

Tags: android, android-studio

Help. After I update my Android Studio,
This problem appeared.

[image]

Comment: Your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable seems to be using backslashes, but you are on Windows

Comment: I have solved the problem by Updating the Android Emulator in SDK. thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to my android studio at the moment, but I hope this solution is clear enough:
He's trying to launch an emulator from a wrong path, by emulator `\emulator/qemu/.../`, must be `\emulator\qemu\...\\`.

So you have to go to your android studio preferences and edit the source.

Answer (score -1):

Try this below path in bash file with your location of emulator

function emulator { cd "/Users/kirankumar/Library/Android/sdk/tools/" && ./emulator "$@"; }